# Основы синтаксиса

Tags: php, синтаксис

Что означает выражение `$i%3 == 0`?

Answer (score 3):

Это условное выражение, возвращает true или false
Возвращает `true`, если остаток от деления `$i` на `3` равен `0`
Иначе возвращает `false`

`$i` - это переменная, переменные `$i`, `$j` очень часто используются в циклах в качестве счетчиков, то есть они изменяются в каждой итерации цикла

`%` - это арифметический оператор, который называется "Деление по модулю", он возвращает целочисленный остаток от деления

[Арифметические операторы в php](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

`==` - это оператор сравнения в php, возвращает `true` если обе переменные после преобразования типов равны, иначе возвражает `false`

[Операторы сравнения php](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: а зачем `$`  перед `i`?

Comment: @4per "Имена всех переменных в PHP должны начинаться со знака $ — так интерпретатору значительно легче "понять" и отличить их, например, в строках." [Общие понятия о переменных в PHP](http://www.php.su/learnphp/vars/?basic)

Answer (score 0):

Это выражение вернет `true`, если остаток от деления переменной `$i` на 3 равен 0, и `false`, если он не равен 0.